# Should I expect lower R2 with meta-regression in meta-analyses with low heterogeneity?

Tags: regression, meta-regression, heterogeneity

The question in short: Should I expect lower R<sup>2</sup> values in meta-regression performed in a meta-analysis with low levels of heterogeneity?

In meta-analysis, I<sup>2</sup> represents a ratio of between-study variance to total variance. So, in analyses with low I<sup>2</sup>, the majority of variance is due to within-study error. There is smaller quantity of 'true' difference between study effect sizes.

If that is the case, when meta-regression is performed for a meta-analysis with low levels of heterogeneity (i.e. 10-30%), should we expect lower R<sup>2</sup> values. As I understand it, R<sup>2</sup> describes the fraction of total variance that can be accounted for by a given covariate. If the majority of variance is due to within-study variance (which covariates have nothing to do with), shouldn't I expect any given covariate to explain less of the total variance?

I want to make sure I am understanding these concepts correctly. Any clarification is appreciated.